# Website opening issue if user is behind proxy

Tags: php, apache, proxy, http-headers

Angular 6 project with PHP back-end is given (on a classic Apache server).

Everything works very well from localhost and production server as well. But once my friend tried to login from his university (he was behind a proxy there), it didn't work.

We can see the followings in the OPTIONS request response headers:

```
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Via: 1.0 firewall.uninamehere.com:3128 (squid)
X-Cache: MISS from firewall.uninamehere.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from firewall.uninamehere.com:3128
```

That's all.

After OPTIONS a login POST request should start. But it doesn't...

He said that the proxy is shhh for a while, and sometimes WIFI also does not work.

**The questions are:**

- Is the problem on our side?
- Can we do anything with it?

Comment: It's likely only because his university is blocking your site. You should try accessing it from a McDonalds's wifi or something if you really want to see if a proxy is the issue.

Comment: Actually I have tried it out behind my corporate proxy. It worked.

Comment: Then like I said above it's probably just his university blocking the site. Unfortunately some businesses and most schools will block all sites that aren't approved to be on the network. Best of luck :)

Comment: First you should precisely define what "didn't work" means and then share that with us.

Comment: @castis as I wrote that the webpage opened, when he tried to login (with username + pass), it didn't work, nothing happened. OPTIONS request was sent, but POST wasn't, because we got 500 with the OPTIONS response headers above.